# Technical meaning of "in" and "on" in a corollary to Hurwitz' theorem.

Tags: complex-analysis

In [Conway, p.152](http://math.unice.fr/~nivoche/pdf/Conway1.pdf), the corollary at the bottom of the page reads:

> **2.6 Corollary.** If $\{f_n\}\subset H(G)$ converges to $f$ in $H(G)$ and each $f_n$ never vanishes on $G$ then either $f\equiv 0$ or $f$ never vanishes.

I am a little cautious as to read this corollary correctly, as I know Hurwitz' theorem, from which the corollary results, fails if the chosen boundary contains a zero.

Am I correct in thinking that "$\{f_n\}\subset H(G)$ converges to $f$ **in** $H(G)$" refers to the open set $G$, whereas "each $f_n$ never vanishes **on** $G$" refers to the boundary of $G$ (sometimes denoted $\partial G$)?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Converges in often means that the limit is in $H(G)$, and not its closure.

Comment: "converges to $f$ in $H(G)$" is a statement about the topology with respect to which the sequence converges. It means that the sequence converges locally uniformly on $G$, equivalently: the convergence is uniform on every compact subset of $G$,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  In both cases, in/on $G$ refer to the region $G$.  Since $G$ is open, any $\overline{B}(a;R) \subset G$ is a positive distance from $\partial G$.  So your potentially problematic zeroes on the boundary of this disk are also interior to $G$.

Comment: @Antinous : Thanks for catching the typo and fixing it.